# Deep learning for Hand Detection

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

how can I use deep learning for hand detection. Are there any articles or tutorials or any relevant links regarding hand detection using deep learning. Please let me know. What will be the approach or steps for hand detection

Comment: Google? I know nothing of the subject but typed in this title and got hundreds of results. Kind of an overly broad question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although the question may be broad, there is a very high-level reasonable answer.

Probably the most success you'll have is by fine tuning a pre-trained image classification convolutional neural network model such as VGG16, Inception, VGG19, or ResNet.

For this case, you can use Python, VGG19, and Keras. You can grab a pre-trained VGG19 model for Keras here.

https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/8d096f48a1be4a2d660d

First, gather as many images of hands that you can (2000 would be a pretty solid number to start with), and a close to equal number of not-hand images, and put them into their respective directories. Pre-process the images so that they're all 224x224 pixels. This is required for the VGG19 pre-trained model.

Next, you need to fine-tune the model. You can find the details in the link, but the gist is that you pop off the final 1000-node fully connected layer, and replace with the 2-node fully connected layer that consists of the categories for hand, and not-hand images.

https://flyyufelix.github.io/2016/10/03/fine-tuning-in-keras-part1.html

Import your images into a numpy array where each image is represented by a 50176 dimensional vector. You can actually create a matrix with 50176 rows, and the number of images.

In addition, create 2 dimensional one-hot vectors for you labels where [1 0] is for hand images, and [0 1] is for non-hand images.

Fit your data into the pre-trained model by grabbing the reference to the Keras model object in the VGG19.

```
model.fit(image_data, one_hot_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

I won't go into detail on epochs, batch_size, validation data, etc, but you want to make sure you keep an eye on how well your validation data is predicting, it's usually a descent predictor for testing accuracy on the pre-trained models. You can use the evaluate function to get an accuracy score.

```
model.evaluate(image_validation_data, validation_labels, batch_size=32)
```

Once the model is trained, and the validation accuracy is reasonable, you can use the predict function to test whether you have a hand image.

```
model.predict(test_images, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
```

For more information, I would highly recommend the fast.ai course.

For a more detailed explanation of Convolutional Neural Networks, with all the math, and theory, Stanford's CS231n class is a must.